# How to display the textfield value in picker selected row in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I have a pickerview. In that picker I am displaying values from 1 to 100. When I select a value in picker say 2 that value is displayed in a textfield. I want that if my textfield contains value say 5 that value particular value should get displayed in my picker.

Now problem is when in textfield 5 is displayed and I go to pickerview it shows by default every time 1 selected irrespective of the value in the texfield. I want the value which is present in the textfield should get displayed on the pickerview also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code it will help you

```
[picker selectRow:[yourTxtObj.text intValue]-1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[yourPickerViewName selectRow:[textfield.text intValue] inComponent:yourComponent animated:YES]
```

This will  work. It is used for select a row in picker.